# Stack Overflow Jobs usando perfil do SOpt

Tags: novo-recurso, careers

Não teremos o Jobs tão cedo do Brasil, se é que teremos um dia. Mas é sabido que empresas brasileiras usam a plataforma para contratar.

Mas será que é possível usar o perfil do SOpt para Jobs no lugar ou adicionalmente ao perfil do SOen? Pelo que entendo isso tem mudanças importantes da recomendação de vagas.

Comment: Se tivesse um jobs ele seria do Brasil e não da lingua portuguesa (i.e. teria que criar um para cada região)?

Comment: @Blogueira eu acho que sim, porque aí envolve algo mais localizado, estrutura, não é só jogar na web e deixar o povo usar.